# can we assign product of 2 int values to unsigned long long int

Tags: c++

Chef is the new king of the country Chefland. As first and most important responsibility he wants to reconstruct the road system of Chefland. There are N (1 to N) cities in the country and each city i has a population Pi. Chef wants to build some bi-directional roads connecting different cities such that each city is connected to every other city (by a direct road or through some other intermediate city) and starting from any city one can visit every other city in the country through these roads. Cost of building a road between two cities u and v is Pu x Pv. Cost to build the road system is the sum of cost of every individual road that would be built.

Help king Chef to find the minimum cost to build the new road system in Chefland such that every city is connected to each other.

given constraints
1 ≤ T ≤ 10
1 ≤ N ≤ 105
1 ≤ Pi ≤ 106

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    int t,n;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
    cin>>n;
    int p[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    cin>>p[i];
    }
    sort(p,p+n);
    unsigned long long int cost=0;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
    cost+=p[i]*p[0];    
    }
    cout<<cost<<endl;   
    }
    }
// the above one is not accepted 

but below one is accepted

    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        int T ;
        cin>>T ;
        while(T--)
        {
            long long int N ;
            cin>>N ;
            vector<long long int> v ;
            while(N--)
            {
                long long int x ;
                cin>>x ;
                v.push_back(x);
            }
            long long int cost=0 ;
            sort(v.begin() , v.end());
            for (int i=1 ; i<v.size() ; i++)
            {
                cost+=v[i]*v[0];
            }
            cout<<cost<<endl ;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: what is the question? what is the output you want? please change the description to purely technical. tell what is not working

Comment: BTW, online judges don't care about compilation or build times (unless they are excessive, like in minutes).  Using more descriptive variable names will make your program more readable and has negligible affect on the build time and zero impact to your execution time.  More readable code means less defects and helps other people understand and debug your code.

Comment: BTW, `int p[t]` is not standard C++.  It may be allowed as an extension with some compilers.  Replace with `std::vector<int> p(t);`.

Comment: If you are going to use `unsigned long long int`, you should change all the integer types to `unsigned int`.  Conversion between `signed int` and `unsigned int` may produces some issues; better to keep everything signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your question is how to safely multiply two `int` values and store result in `long long`:

In C++ the type of the arithmetic expression is determined by type of operands. For example, if you write `a * b` with `a` and `b` being 32 bit integers (`int`), the result will also be `int`, even if later you cast it to `long long`. This can obviously cause an overflow. In order to get a true 64-bit result you need to cast one of the arguments to a 64 bit integer (`long long`):

```cpp
int a, b;
long long c;
// WRONG: c = a * b;
c = static_cast<long long>(a) * b;
```